# How to wait for reaction and only then send message [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a message that my bots sends (ban command) and then reacts to, then the bot checks the reaction and sends another message and reacts to it as well. Anyway, after that the bot should send a confirmation messages and that's it. But, the bot sends the message right after it sends the first messages, without waiting for a reaction. How can I fix this?

(the last message [and GuildMember#ban] being sent right after the first message that although it should wait for a reaction):

```
bannedUser.ban({ days: banDuration, reason: banReason }).catch(err => {

    console.log(err)
    message.channel.send(`An error occured: ${err}`)
})

message.channel.send({ embed: banConfirmation })
```

the whole thing:

```
        let bannedUser = message.mentions.members.first()
        let banDuration;
        let banReason;

        const noPermsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":x: You do not have permission to perform this command!")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const UserDoesNotExistEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":warning: This user is not a member of this server.")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.warn)

        const banEmbedReason = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You are about to ban ${bannedUser.username}, first pick a reason for the ban.`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a reason for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: Use of bad language', value: 'Ban the user for use of inappropriate language in the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: Insulting a member', value: 'Ban the user for insulting memebers on the server for any reason' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: Spamming in the server', value: 'Ban the user for spamming messages on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content', value: 'Ban the user for sending inappropriate content on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: Other..', value: 'For a differnet reason, write the reason in chat, like "$banreason <reason>"' }, { name: ':x: None', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const banEmbedDuration = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Now, please pick a duration for the ban`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a duration for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: 1 day', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: 3 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: 7 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: 14 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: 28 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':infinity: Forever', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const banConfirmation = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You sucessfully banned ${bannedUser.username}.`)
            .setDescription(`You have sucessfuly banned ${bannedUser} from the server.`)
            .addFields({ name: ':timer: Ban duration:', value: `${banDuration} days. (0 days = forever)` }, { name: ':page_with_curl:', value: `"${banReason}"` })
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.success)

        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS'])) {
            message.channel.send(noPermsEmbed)
            return
        }

        if (!message.guild.member(bannedUser)) {
            message.channel.send(UserDoesNotExistEmbed)
            return
        }

        message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedReason }).then(embedMessage => {

            embedMessage.react("");
            embedMessage.react("");
            embedMessage.react("");
            embedMessage.react("");
            embedMessage.react("❌");

            const reasonFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', '', '', '', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            embedMessage.awaitReactions(reasonFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedDuration }).then(embedMessage => {

                    embedMessage.react("");
                    embedMessage.react("");
                    embedMessage.react("");
                    embedMessage.react("");
                    embedMessage.react("");
                    embedMessage.react("♾️");

                    const durationFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                        return ['', '', '', '', '', '♾️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                    };

                    embedMessage.awaitReactions(durationFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                        const durationReaction = collected.first()

                        if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banDuration = 1
                        } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banDuration = 3
                        } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banDuration = 7
                        } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banDuration = 14
                        } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banDuration = 28
                        } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '♾️') {
                            banDuration = 0 //infinite
                        }
                    })
                })

                const reasonReaction = collected.first()

                if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    banReason = "Use of bad language"
                } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    banReason = "Insulting a member"
                } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    banReason = "Spamming in the server"
                } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    banReason = "NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content"
                } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                    banReason = "None specified"
                }
            })
        })

        bannedUser.ban({ days: banDuration, reason: banReason }).catch(err => {

            console.log(err)
            message.channel.send(`An error occured: ${err}`)
        })

        message.channel.send({ embed: banConfirmation })

    }
```

(the undefined(s) in the picture are not related to the problem, it's just that the green stripe message get's sent before the user can react to the first message. i fixed the undefined problem already)

It results with:

[image]

updated code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json")

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans a user from your server.',
    execute(message, args) {

        let bannedUser = message.mentions.members.first()
        let banDuration;
        let banReason;

        const noPermsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":x: You do not have permission to perform this command!")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const UserDoesNotExistEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":warning: This user is not a member of this server.")
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.warn)

        const banEmbedReason = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You are about to ban ${bannedUser.user.username}, first pick a reason for the ban.`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a reason for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: Use of bad language', value: 'Ban the user for use of inappropriate language in the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: Insulting a member', value: 'Ban the user for insulting memebers on the server for any reason' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: Spamming in the server', value: 'Ban the user for spamming messages on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content', value: 'Ban the user for sending inappropriate content on the server' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: Other..', value: 'For a differnet reason, write the reason in chat, like "$banreason <reason>"' }, { name: ':x: None', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const banEmbedDuration = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Now, please pick a duration for the ban`)
            .setDescription("Please pick a duration for your ban first")
            .addFields({ name: ':regional_indicator_a: 1 day', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_b: 3 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_c: 7 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_d: 14 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':regional_indicator_e: 28 days', value: '\u200b' }, { name: ':infinity: Forever', value: '\u200b' }, )
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.err)

        const banConfirmation = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You sucessfully banned ${bannedUser.user.username}.`)
            .setDescription(`You have sucessfuly banned ${bannedUser} from the server.`)
            .addFields({ name: ':timer: Ban duration:', value: `${banDuration} days. (0 days = forever)` }, { name: ':page_with_curl: Ban reason:', value: `"${banReason}"` })
            .setColor(botconfig.colors.success)

        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS'])) {
            message.channel.send(noPermsEmbed)
            return
        }

        if (!message.guild.member(bannedUser)) {
            message.channel.send(UserDoesNotExistEmbed)
            return
        }

        message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedReason }).then(embedMessage => {

            const reasonFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', '', '', '', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            embedMessage.react("")
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react(""))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react("❌"))
                .then(() => {
                    embedMessage.awaitReactions(reasonFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                        message.channel.send({ embed: banEmbedDuration }).then(embedMessage => {

                            embedMessage.react("");
                            embedMessage.react("");
                            embedMessage.react("");
                            embedMessage.react("");
                            embedMessage.react("");
                            embedMessage.react("♾️");

                            const durationFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                                return ['', '', '', '', '', '♾️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                            };

                            embedMessage.awaitReactions(durationFilter, { max: 1, time: 120000 }).then(collected => {

                                const durationReaction = collected.first()

                                if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                    banDuration = 1
                                } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                    banDuration = 3
                                } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                    banDuration = 7
                                } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                    banDuration = 14
                                } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                                    banDuration = 28
                                } else if (durationReaction.emoji.name === '♾️') {
                                    banDuration = 0 //infinite
                                }
                            })
                        })

                        const reasonReaction = collected.first()

                        if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Use of bad language"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Insulting a member"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "Spamming in the server"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            banReason = "NSFW/harmful/inappropriate content"
                        } else if (reasonReaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                            banReason = "None specified"
                        }
                    })
                })
        }).then(() => {

            bannedUser.ban({ days: banDuration, reason: banReason }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                message.channel.send(`An error occured: ${err}`)
            })

            message.channel.send({ embed: banConfirmation })
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to wait for your bot to put on the reactions before waiting for them, otherwise it will detect itself. (Using the .react function is basically sending a promise, and it can finish after your await starts.)

You can do this in such way:

```
message.react('')
    .then(() => message.react(''))
    .then(() => message.react(''))
    .then(() => message.awaitReactions(<...>).then((...) => {...})
```

(It's only some pseudo code.)

Comment: Still doesnt work.. added updated code at the bottom of the q.

Comment: I made it work! Just needed to understand the .then() tree and once i did i fixed it ez

Comment: The end part where you send the confirmation is a ```then``` of the first ```send```. This results in sending the first message, then sending the second. You should place the ```then```part of the confirmation message to the end of the await reaction.

Comment: Oh, you figured it out while I was typing. Well, have a nice day.

Comment: Yeah lol. Thank you SO much. Promises have always been my worst part of js.. 